# Python 3. Json. Добавить данные в словарь

Tags: python, json

Есть список с внутренним словарём:

```
[
    {
        "users":[{
            "name":"Joe",
            "date":"01.01.2000",
            "city":"Nevada"
        }]
    }
]
```

Как добавить в словарь `users` данные ("name", "date", "city")?

Пробовал так:

```
def write_to_json(name,date,city):
    with open('user_info.json','w') as jf:
        jf_file = json.load('user_info.json')
        jf_target = jf_file[0]['users']

        user_info = {'name':name,'date':date,'city':city}
        dump_info = jf_target.append(user_info)

        json.dump(dump_info,jf)

info = input("Name, date (d.m.y), city: ").split()

name = info[0]
date = info[1]
city = info[2]

write_to_json(name,date,city)
```

Но данные записываются вне словаря главного списка.

Comment: `d["users"]` это не словарь—это список, который содержит словарь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` добавляет элемент к списку, но не возвращает список, т.е. вместо

```
dump_info = jf_target.append(user_info)
```

пишете просто

```
jf_target.append(user_info)
```

а при записи в json файл используйте

```
json.dump(jf_file,jf).
```

Также смущает строка `jf_file = json.load('user_info.json')`, возможно используется нестандартный модуль json, т.к. иначе `load` просил бы не имя файла, а объект с методом `.read`.

Итого такой код:

```
import json

def write_to_json(name, date, city):
    with open('test.json','r') as jfr:
        jf_file = json.load(jfr)
    with open('test.json','w') as jf:
        jf_target = jf_file[0]['users']
        user_info = {'name': name, 'date': date, 'city': city}
        jf_target.append(user_info)
        json.dump(jf_file, jf, indent=4)

write_to_json('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Из документа:

```
[{
        "users" : [{
                "name" : "Joe",
                "date" : "01.01.2000",
                "city" : "Nevada"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

делает:

```
[{
        "users" : [{
                "date" : "01.01.2000",
                "city" : "Nevada",
                "name" : "Joe"
            }, {
                "date" : "bar",
                "city" : "baz",
                "name" : "foo"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Во-первых, он перезаписывает файл, удаляя старые данные. Режим `"a"` (добавление) не подходит. Но мне надо добавлять в него данные. Во-вторых, мне нужно обновлять один файл, а не перезаписывать из другого.

Comment: В примере были использованы два файла, исключительно для удобства отладки (чтобы не восстанавливать содержимое исходного файла каждый раз после запуска), но ничего не мешает использовать один и тот же файл (например сначала откройте на чтение, прочитайте, затем откройте на запись, запишите). Обновил ответ.